# Admin Module not appears

Tags: module, admin, adminhtml, menu, adminmenu

I'm doing a admin module, but I do not get module tab appears in admin menu.

Here is my config.xml inside Company/LeadPEC/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <company_leadpec>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </company_leadpec>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <leadpec>
        <class>Company_Leadpec_Helper</class>
      </leadpec>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <leadpec>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Company_LeadPEC</module>
          <frontName>leadpec</frontName>
        </args>
      </leadpec>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <leadpec translate="title" module="LeadPEC">
        <title>Company LeadPEC</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <action>admin_leadpec/adminhtml_leadpec</action>
      </leadpec>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <leadpec translate="title" module="LeadPEC">
              <title>Company LeadPEC</title>
              <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            </leadpec>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Here is my controller in Company/LeadPEC/controllers/Adminhtml/LeadpecController.php

```
class Company_Leadpec_Adminhtml_LeadpecController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
        protected function _initAction()
        {
                $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("leadpec/leadpec")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Leadpec Manager"),Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Leadpec Manager"));
                return $this;
        }
        public function indexAction() 
        {
                $this->_title($this->__("Leadpec"));
                $this->_title($this->__("Manager Leadpec"));

                $this->_initAction();
                $this->renderLayout();
        }
}
```

Helper in Company/LeadPEC/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Company_Leadpec_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

app/etc/modules/Company_LeadPEC.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_LeadPEC>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_LeadPEC>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In config.xml global helpers replace with below,**

```
<global>
    <helpers>
      <leadpec>
        <class>Company_LeadPEC_Helper</class>
      </leadpec>
    </helpers>
  </global>
```

Controller in **Company/LeadPEC/controllers/Adminhtml/LeadpecController.php**

```
class Company_LeadPEC_Adminhtml_LeadpecController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  protected function _initAction()
  {
          $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("leadpec/leadpec")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Leadpec Manager"),Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Leadpec Manager"));
          return $this;
  }
  public function indexAction() 
  {
          $this->_title($this->__("Leadpec"));
          $this->_title($this->__("Manager Leadpec"));

          $this->_initAction();
          $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

Helper in Company/LeadPEC/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Company_LeadPEC_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Seems to looklike issue with your LeadPEC character conflict in your module.

Comment: Thank you! This was a fail but it not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found your **adminhtml** tag is not closed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <company_leadpec>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </company_leadpec>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <leadpec>
        <class>Company_Leadpec_Helper</class>
      </leadpec>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <leadpec>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Company_LeadPEC</module>
          <frontName>leadpec</frontName>
        </args>
      </leadpec>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <leadpec translate="title" module="LeadPEC">
        <title>Company LeadPEC</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <action>admin_leadpec/adminhtml_leadpec</action>
      </leadpec>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <leadpec translate="title" module="LeadPEC">
              <title>Company LeadPEC</title>
              <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            </leadpec>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
 </adminhtml>
</config>
```